# find full path given partial path

Tags: shell, unix, find

I know how to find files using

```
find . -name "file_name"
```

But if I am given one part of a path, say "folder1/subfolder2/", how do I get all the full path that contains this partial path?

**Example**

partial path: `folder1/subfolder2/`

desire result:

```
/bob/folder1/subfolder2/yo/
/sandy/folder1/subfolder2/hi/
```

Comment: You'd have to build a wrapper around the `find` utility (so maybe an `alias`), since neither the utility itself nor the found files know anything about an absolute path.

Comment: And a remark to your example: the `find` utility will never find two files as you suggest in your desired result, _except_ if they are both contained inside the folder the path specified in the call of `find` points to, so `.` here. That would mean, that in your example `.` would have to point to `/`, otherwise that result would not be possible. And in _that_ case, all you lack is the leading `/` in the path the utility already outputs. So if you try `find / -name "file_name"` you will actually get your desired absolute paths ;-)

Comment: a quick workaround is to `find / -name "folder1" | grep "folder1/folder2"`

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Use the `-path` option:

```
find . -path '*/folder1/subfolder2/*'
```

Answer (score 4):

You may do it like below:

```
find . -path "*folder1/folder2" -prune -exec find {} -type f -name file.txt \;
```

With `-prune` you don't recurse after first match in a directory

Comment: Did you left `*folder1/folder2` unquoted on purpose ?

Answer (score 2):

This one worked for me (using bash)

```
ls -l /**/folder1/subfolder2/**
```

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this, other solutions did not work for me,

find1 is a function

```
find1 ()
{
    for file in `find -name $1`;
    do
        full_path=$PWD/$file;
        echo $full_path;
    done
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want to stay posix-compliant, at least on Linux you can also use the `-regex` (and `-regextype`) option for this purpose.

For instance:

```
find folder/ -regextype posix-extended -regex "(.*/)?deer/(.*/)?beer"
```

will match

```
folder/deer/beer
folder/deer/dir/forest/beer/
folder/forest/deer/dir/forest/beer/
```

etc.

See linux man for details.